# Как мне сгруппировать родителей и детей?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

у меня есть субъекты, по которым я получаю подразделения:

```
var departments = subjects
   .Select(subject => subject.Department)
   .Where(department => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(department.ParentDepartmentId))
   .GroupBy(department => department.ParentDepartmentId)
   .ToDictionary(
       department => department.Key,
       department => department.ToList());
```

затем я получаю всех родителей, т.е "путь вверх":

```
var departmentsIds = subjects.Select(department => department.Department?.Id);
var childDepartments = await _departmentClient
    .GetByChildrenIds(departmentsIds)
    .Unwrap();
```

у меня не получается сгруппировать, я не знаю, как подступить
на выходе я хочу получить словарь, где ключом является ребенок, а в значениях - список родителей, т.е "путь вверх"

Comment: Если вы хотите получить ответ, то стоит позаботиться о том, чтоб люди не додумывали половину самостоятельно, а работали с уже заготовленными данными. Сделайте новый, чистый, консольный проект, создайте в нем "предка" и "родителя", создайте коллекцию этих объектов, и заполните ее, а потом на основе этих данных, попытайтесь воспроизвести вашу проблему. Со всем этим приходите сюда, прикладывайте все это, и также указывайте то, какой вид на выходе хотите получить, будем тогда думать. А то сейчас, ваш вопрос из разряда "вот данные, думайте как сделать сами".

Comment: Присоединяюсь к предыдущему комментатору - ничегошеньки непонятно

Comment: хорошо, я освобожусь и обновлю код